# Authentication Flow with Local User Database and Identity Provider, from Web and/or Mobile device

Tags: openid-connect, idp

We have a web application that supports two forms of login: one form uses an internal user database, and the other form uses either SSO or an external Identity Provider. A successful login results in a Session cookie being created for the user, to permit further operations to occur.

SSO in our cases means Windows Integrated Security, and Identity Provider would be something OpenId-Connect compliant. Our internal user database is simple username/password based, potentially with 2FA -- this was our "original" authentication capability.

The two forms of login are simply handled via two different URLs at present. This is pretty ordinary, but in practical terms once an organisation starts using SSO/Idp they would rarely need the other form of login, and it mainly exists for "administration".

We also have a mobile application that uses the API of the web application to conduct its work. It does not currently support an Identity Provider and only supports the internal user login.

From the perspective of the mobile device, what is the usual or best practice approach for dealing with an authentication flow when the user might need to login via the internal user database or via an Identity Provider? Do we simply ask them "up-front" what type of user they are logging in as and proceed accordingly? Or do we get them to enter their user-ID first and then try make a decision from that (and what are the security implications of that arrangements, eg. probing)?

Do we need to build a "thin" IDP layer on on web tier for our mobile app to talk to, so the mobile app thinks it is dealing with a standard Identity Provider and the web tier redirects off to a "real" Identity Provider (Okta, Azure, etc) when required? Building even a thin IDP strikes me as re-inventing the wheel and so forth.

Finally, is it preferable for the mobile application to use a session-based authorisation scheme or a bearer token based authorisation scheme? Currently we're using a session-based scheme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pure OIDC approach would look like this:

**APPLICATIONS**

Both web and mobile clients only run a code flow and know absolutely nothing about authentication methods. A mobile app would use the techniques from [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252) to receive login responses. Apps then use access tokens to call APIs. A web app would use up to date recommendations for [browser based apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps), meaning that is has an application cookie layer.

The access token (combined with a refresh token to periodically renew it) represents an API based session, and applications should not usually need to deal with other types of session.

**AUTHENTICATION METHODS**

The authorization server should support many primary authentication methods. They can also be chained together to form MFA workflows. It can connect to existing databases or LDAP stores to verify credentials. Or it can use many other possible options, such as Google sign in, WebAuthn, email verification, App2App and so on. A default authentication method can be overridden in a couple of ways:

- If only employees use the override, consider getting them to supply a custom setting, eg in a web query parameter of `auth=password` or a mobile config setting. The app can then preselect the authentication method to use by sending an [acr_values](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) query parameter to the authorization server.
- Sometimes end users themselves may have varying authentication methods. An example might be where some users have set a preference to use passwordless logins, eg via WebAuthn. In such cases, a useful technique is to configure a `username authenticator` that prompts for some kind of user identifier, such as an email, then runs a custom action to look up the authentication preference. The user identifier might then be remembered in a cookie, to avoid the user needing to type their email on every login.

**CLEANEST ARCHITECTURE**

The end goal should always be simplest and most extensible code in applications, and giving them the best security capabilities. An important factor is identifying your own architectural requirements, then using an identity system that meets them. When this is not the case, complexity grows as you add more apps.

Comment: I’ve understood everything you’ve said but it’s not clear to me who does this work? Are you saying we roll our own front-end to provide prompt the user up-front and then hand off to one of various with various back-end identity providers? Or do existing identity providers have these capabilities? I’m still not sure what pieces are provided/built by who.